# Error al ejecutar webpack: Cannot find module '/webpack/webpack.server.config.js'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Es la primera vez que estoy intentando usar webpack para desarrollar aplicaciones con react. En el `webpack.server.config.js` tengo el siguiente código:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './source/server.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: './built/server',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json',
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        query: {
          presets: ['latest-minimal', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  target: 'node',
}
```

En el archivo `webpack.config.js` tengo lo siguiente:

```
const server = require('./webpack/webpack.server.config.js');

module.exports = [
  server,
];
```

Ya instalé webpack, incluso con `sudo npm i -g webpack`, pero cuando ejecuto en la consola de ubuntu el comando webpack me sale el siguiente error:

[image: Cannot find module '/webpack/webpack.server.config.js']

Si alguien me puede indicar por qué no funciona, le agradezco mucho.

Comment: ¿Podrías definir la estructura de directorios?  Es un problema de resolución de rutas, webpack no encuentra `webpack/webpack.server.config.js`.

Comment: Coincidiendo con @guzgarcia, el problema es que cuando usas `./` estas diciendo que esta en ese mismo directorio. Si `webpack.config.js` esta en el mismo directorio que `webpack.server.config.js`, simplemente el require deberia ser: `require('./webpack.server.config.js')`